# where get value of textbox in register page in opencart 2x?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

i want to add text box for give any data from customer where register new customer in site:

add text box in form register but i dont know how to get and save in mysql and variable .

example:

create `textbox` in `view/theme/defult/account/register.tpl`
:

```
<div class="form-group required">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-telephone"><?php echo $entry_telephone; ?></label>
   <div class="col-sm-tel">
      <input type="tel" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_telephone; ?>" id="input-telephone" class="tel" />
          <?php if ($error_Tel) { ?>
          <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_Tel; ?></div>
          <?php } ?>

        </div>
```

`placerholder` is show in `textbox` but no show value entered in textbox when error confirm page and reload register page for enter ok data in textbox.

i want know how to save value of textbox in `$telephone` (where refrence?!!! in directory)

and how to save in data of textbox in mysql?

opencart 2.3.0.2

Answer (score 3):

Opencart uses MVC model which means:

- template files (.twig or .tpl) are stored in view directory
- controller files (codes that do processing and these kind of stuff) are stored in controller directory
- model files (codes that do communications with database) are stored in model directory

So in order to use check box:

1. You have to go to:

   Catalog/controller/account/register 
   Here you can write codes that are responsible for validating checkbox, giving it a default value, etc
2. Go to:

   Catalog/model/account/customer 
   And rewrite the sql query

P.s: opencart 2 provides a feature called custom field. You can add diffenret kind of fields to register page using this feature. Custom fields is located under customers in admin panel's menu

Comment: test and find but not clear for get value of textbox in variable.where know to get `value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>"`

Comment: To get the value use: $this->request->post['telephone'];

Comment: test and comback